# Overriding Bootstrap 3 CSS styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this style:

```
.form-style{
   margin: 50px auto;/* also tried margin: 50px auto !important; */
   /* other styles */
 }
```

And I use it in my div element like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="myDiv" class="form-style col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<p>This is a text.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

If I don't use `form-style` my div is appear at the center. But I want to use `form-style` and when I use it, the margin property of the `form-style` will prevent the bootstrap `col-md-offset-3` to make my div center. How can I override the parent margin so that it haven't been set for my div?

If I remove the `margin` from `form-style` it works fine. But I can't remove the margin since it is used in other parts of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want something like this as it seems a *hack* but your issue is that your element is **floating** that's why the margin auto is not working, so you need to remove the floating to make it working. *(but it's not a good idea as it will make bootstrap behave strange)*

```css
.form-style {
  margin: 50px auto!important;
  float: none!important;
  /* other styles */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class=container>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="myDiv" class="form-style col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
      <p>This is a text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I didn't understand about float. can you please explain more?

Comment: @JeanA Bootstrap 3 rely on floating element to create their layout, they have the property `float:left` which make them behave differently from non-floating element and that's why margin auto don't work. You can read more here : https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ and you will understand how floating elements works ;)

Comment: Also if I use !important the margin will be useless in all of the children? If so why should I have the margin at all?

Comment: @JeanA margin won't affect children ... and i can't tell if yes or no you should have margin :) i don't know your whole code and what you want to achieve, but as i said in my answer it looks more a *hack* what you want to try as it's not good to try forcing things like this. Am pretty sure you can do what you need with bootstrap classes only :)

Answer (score 0):

From your question is seems that you don't want to replace the offset value of left to right, but want the `margin` set to the top and bottom. If this is the case this will work without any override of Bootstrap values. Also, adding the `div` `id` will not affect any other places that `form-style` is used.

```css
#myDiv.form-style {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div id="myDiv" class="form-style col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <p>This is a text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. But no luck. Same as before.

Comment: Can you update your question with a snippet to include the contents of the `div` so we can see how this is working? It may be that the `div` doesn't have the appropriate styles to accept `auto` as a margin.

Comment: my div has only a simple p tag.

Comment: Okay, and is contained in a `container` and `row`. Maybe add a screenshot of what you are seeing.